# Running React app through Azure WebApp locally

Tags: reactjs, azure, web-applications, deployment

I created a new react app and also a new project on Visual Studio: .NET Framework Web Application, under my Azure subscription.

What should be the process so when I run the Web Application locally, I will see the new react app and not the ASP.NET screen ?

I deployed the new react app to azure so when I run the website I do see the new react app, however when I run it from the .sln file, I get this screen:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think the step you missed is to update the **Index** view which is used to generate the website root to include the bootstrapping of the **React** app. It should be located at *Views/Home/Index.cshtml* or *Pages/Index.cshtml*, depending on the template you used when you created the project.

As a side note, I would consider dropping the ASP.Net project entirely and just use **VS Code** for the **React** app, through there you can easily deploy your app to an **Azure Storage Account** using the new [Static website hosting in Azure Storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website), thus removing the need for an ASP.Net website.

Hope it helps!

Comment: As I need to configure my webApp to work with Azure storage table I'm afraid I will still need to use the .Net project as it will be the server or "hosting" side. Also, can you please elaborate about the first part of your answer? thanks!

Comment: I would still separate it to two different projects: one for the React app and one for the server side API, which in turn has access to the Azure table. Using the Azure Storage Static Website hosting will save both technical issues (due to npm compatibility issues) and cost, as downloading the API won't utilize VM resources

Comment: Regarding the update required for the Index view, the most simple way for you to see how the React app needs to be integrate, will be to generate an ASP.Net Core React app (it is available on the wizard when creating a ASP.Net App)

Comment: Well I will try this out. Toda Raba :)

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: Hi Itay, I see what you mean by generating a new ASP.Net Core React app. I just did it and it definitely makes more sense. However, I would still need to keep working with my .NET Framework (Instructions from above). I adopted your advice of working on the client (react project) and the server (which has an access to Azure Table Storage) separately. The only thing left now is to configure Index.cshtml to know my react project. What should I change in index.cshtml ?

Comment: I would manage to separate projects, one for the React app and one for the API that communicates with the table and deploy them separately